OpenAPI 3.1.0 - $ref with json path with esaping in it does not work - should it?
I just tried switching my project to OpenAPI 3.1.0 version and found that any $ref with json path in it fails with
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in fragment at index 46: ./some_folder/API.json#/paths/~1path-in-json~1"
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail (URI.java:2976)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars (URI.java:3147)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse (URI.java:3191)
    at java.net.URI.<init> (URI.java:623)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.reference.ReferenceUtils.toBaseURI (ReferenceUtils.java:15)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.reference.ReferenceVisitor.toBaseURI (ReferenceVisitor.java:65)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.reference.ReferenceVisitor.toReference (ReferenceVisitor.java:69)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.reference.ReferenceVisitor.resolveRef (ReferenceVisitor.java:205)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.reference.ReferenceVisitor.visitPathItem (ReferenceVisitor.java:108)

My $ref looks like this:
"$ref": "./some_folder/API.json#/paths/~1path-in-json~1". Inside the target file it points to element:
{
   "paths" :{
        "/path-in-json/" : {
            ...
        }     
   }
}

This worked perfectly in version 3.0.3 and stopped working since I tried changing to new version. I'm using
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.8.0</version>
</plugin>

Is this unsupported anymore, is it a bug in generator or am I missing smth?

Looks like a parser bug. Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues
